# Find the following integral $\int\sqrt{x^2+1} dx.$ Please complete my solution.

Tags: indefinite-integrals, substitution

I am reading a calculus book.
There is the following problem with a hint:

> Find the following integral $$\int\sqrt{x^2+1} dx.$$
> Hint: use the substitution $x+\sqrt{x^2+1}=s$.

I was not able to complete my solution.
My attempt is here:

> $s=x+\sqrt{x^2+1}$.
> $ds=(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}})dx=\frac{s}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx$.
> $dx=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{s}ds$.
> So, $\int\sqrt{x^2+1} dx=\int\frac{x^2+1}{s} ds$.

Please complete my solution.

Comment: The reason you can't use this hint is because you missed the meat of this substitution.  The goal is to "escape from radicals".  Notice, we have to do something so that we eliminate the term with a degree of 2.  If you type $\sqrt{x^2+1}=s+x$, the quadratic term will be eliminated when you square both sides. Then, you can find $x$ in a rational form. This means, you can also use $$\sqrt{x^2+1}=s-x$$

Comment: @lonestudent Thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$\sqrt{x^2+1} = s-x \implies x^2+1 = s^2-2sx+x^2$$

Solve for $x$ and substitute.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

$$s=x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\iff (s-x)^2=x^2+1\iff s^2-2sx=1\iff x=\frac{s^2-1}{2s}=\frac{s}{2}-\frac{1}{2s}.
$$
So, $dx=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{s^2}\right)ds$ and
$$\int(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})dx=\frac{1}{2}\int s\left(1+\frac{1}{s^2}\right)ds=\frac{1}{2}\int \left(s+\frac{1}{s}\right)ds=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{s^2}{2}-\ln|s|\right) +C= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})^2}{2}-\ln|x+\sqrt{x^2+1}|\right)+C.
$$
Finally, $$\int\sqrt{x^2+1}dx=\int(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})dx-\frac{x^2}{2}= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})^2}{2}-\ln|x+\sqrt{x^2+1}|-x^2\right)+C
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\sqrt{x^2+1} dx=\int\frac{x^2+1}{s} ds\quad (*)$$

Right.

$\ s=x+\sqrt{x^2+1}.\ $ If we expand $\ s^2\ $ we get,

$$s^2 = 2xs+1\implies s^2-1=2xs\implies 2x=\frac{s^2-1}{s}$$

and continue trying to find an expression for $x^2$, then substitute into $(*)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.